# Heuristic in parsing null terminated string

Tags: c++, string, parsing, packet, tcp

I am parsing byte packets which may consist of numbers and strings. So the structure of one packet could be  : Int32, Int32, UInt8, String, String, UInt8

What am I wondering about is, if there is any chance the String parsing could be done more effectively then just finding the \0 at the end and creating string from the start index to the end. ( just going through the byte array with loop )

For example, for string length of 10000 (which is possible in what I'am doing) will this make 10k iterations to find null terminator.

My ideas:

a) prefix the string with UInt32 which will store the string length (you won't even need the null terminator)

b) set the string size to fixed size iterations. Every string then will be long for example. 10, 20, 30, and so ... so you will just watch for null terminators at every tenth iteration. For string "12345678" and size 10 will be two other characters \0 (this may take a lot of space if not set properly)

Is there any other approach that is really fast and easy to implement? Which one should I use and what may fails in my ideas?

Thank you

Comment: It's usually not a problem to make 10k iterations, as you need anyway 10k times copying the character anyway. I would however prefer having prefixed length, as this allows allocating the buffer of needed length in advance, so that you won't need to keep old packets (containing string start) while scanning for string end.

Comment: Well, I would say, 10k iterations on hardware with /20 computation speed from pc may be a problem. But I may be wrong since I don't have any benchmarks

Comment: To save some bytes, when you are using prefixed size, you can use UTF-8-like encoding for integer value, the size of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small custom serialization tasks like you describe I have always handled strings with a length prefix (your option A). The efficiency benefits are debatable if you have to treat your data as a stream but if you have the whole lot in memory and you need to skip over the string then it's much faster (simple pointer addition).

If your serialization is part of a bigger system then rolling your own isn't a great idea. Systems like [Google Protobuf](https://github.com/google/protobuf/) exist so you don't have to code it yourself.

Comment: Particularly the suggestion to use an existing protocol compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library function like `strlen`. The implementation will use all the reasonable optimizations that exist. 
If you have more control over that data (e.g. send the size as a number), there's no end to what you can do.

For example:

1. Mention the size before the buffer.
2. Send fixed size strings in different packets which contain a continuation bit (if continuation bit is set, append the string found in the next packet, which can also set a continuation bit). This allows more optimizations based on knowing the maximum possible packet size.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "the structure (...) COULD Be `Int32, Int32, Uint8, String, String, UInt8`", so it means that it also can be `Int32, String, Uint8, String, Int32`? Because if packets differs every time You wont even know where the string starts in each packet. But assuming you know the structure and you know where each string starts (or at least first one in your example) you can do `strlen()` to find the end: `strlen(packet+offset_to_start)` - it will actually iterate char after char until `\0` is found. If you want to copy at the same time, you can do strcpy()/strncpy(), but those functions will iterate once again to find the \0 so it's not very efficient. Either use `strcpy()` if you don't need position of the `'\0'` later in code, or use `strlen()` to find the position of the end and use low level memcpy to copy are of given length to char array. I think second option is better, cause knowing the end helps you can calculate how big the destination array should be (and points where second string starts).

If you want to have even more efficient code you can combine your option b) with custom (faster) strlen implementation :)

Also in your example you need to find only `'\0'` between two strings - you know where the end of second one is: sizeof(packet) -sizeof(UInt8). But again, operations like this are easy to define if packet structure is fixed - at least offset from the beginning and the "tail" length (everything not a string) is also well known. I hope this will help you solving the problem, or at least can be a hint.

I assumed you are creating your own packet 'standard' and readers/writers for it. Note that packets in every standard have some more or less predefined structure, so you can follow this rule and have your header (integers, fixed length variables) defined - for example first byte is the length - that's also OK. Then you can use my hints to extract any numbers of strings from actual body.

Comment: I have structure of every packet I am sending and receiving. When there are 2 strings, I assume each ends with \0 at the end.

Comment: So in this case you can do what I wrote: strlen(packet+offset_to_string_start) will give you the length of first string, allocate memory of that size, memcpy to extract your string, then strlen again where starting point is packet+offset+first_string_length, and so on for more strings. Note that the end of last one is at sizeof(packet) - sizeof(end) where end in your case end = sizeof(Int32).